# generate Windows PFX certificate from multiple files

Tags: windows, certificate, x509certificate, pki

in the certlm.msc on a Win Server 2019 machine, I have created a custom CSR / REQ like this [Link](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO29005.html). This req file I sent to the central PKI people of our organisation to get it signed. I now received a CER file and a cc file (for the certificate trust chain). When I import the cer file into the local machine store, it automatically combines the private key with the public key so that the certificate itself is OK and also has the private key.
[image]
The problem is that the certificate does not show the trust chain. Similar to a self signed certificate, the cert itself is the root (friendly name). It does, however, correctly say that it was issued by a CA. Since i do not want to add this cert to the trusted root CA store, I need to somehow integrate the certificate chain (cc file) into the final cert. Any idea which tool I can use to do that in windows? The private key is somewhere on the machine where I created the CSR but not as a separate file.